# How to choose scoring method for Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-science

Do you have any idea that besides R square, is there any other effective and recognizable scoring method to evaluate a Regressor such as Gradient Boosting Regressor, Random Forest Regressor, SVR and so on.

If there are many different scoring methods, what is the factor for us to consider when choosing among them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of overfitting. R-square won't take care of that. You may want to use Adjusted R-square or least square error with component for weights, something like

```
(y - w.x)^2 + lambda*(w.w)
```

where lambda is a weight for restricting model, y is the original output, x is the input, w is the derived weights of the model such that w.x is the predicted output.